Hardhat error - Unrecognized task 'ignition'
I try and run  npx hardhat ignition deploy ignition/modules/myModule.js --network localhost
get Error HH303: Unrecognized task 'ignition'
I'm on 2.22.3 for hardhat versions... so no idea

Have you installed Hardhat ignition and enabled the plugin?

add this in you hardhat.config file
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition";
